# PHP wordwrap string with space in line breaks

Tags: php, string

I have the follow code:

```
$name1 = 'John: ';
$text1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget ligula eu lectus lobortis condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor massa.';
$line1 = $name1 . $text1;
$name2 = 'Richard: ';
$text2 = 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.';
$line2 = $name2 . $text2;

echo wordwrap ($line1,40,"<br>");
echo wordwrap ($line2,40,"<br>");
```

The output will be:

```
John: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur  adipiscing elit. Etiam 
eget ligula eu lectus lobortis
condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor
massa. 
Richard: Pellentesque habitant morbi
tristique senectus et netus et
malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
```

How to wrap the text to output something like this way?

```
John: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur  adipiscing elit. Etiam 
      eget ligula eu lectus lobortis
      condimentum. Aliquam nonummy auctor
      massa. 
Richard: Pellentesque habitant morbi
         tristique senectus et netus et
         malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
```

Please note the `$text` string is formatted to align after `$name` in below lines.

How to output that?

Comment: And what have you tried in order to achieve the outcome you are looking for?

Comment: I hape updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: See my updated answer...

Answer (score 2):

In PHP there is a built in function `wordwrap()` => ***Wraps a string to a given number of characters using a string break character.*** This returns a string to its specified character length.

**Edit: I removed my older answer in favor of the following:**

I think a better method would be to create span tags and place your variables in the tags to ensure you get the perfect indention, or create the illusion of an indention. This would be used in conjunction with a class that adds a flex display to `float` the elements in x axis. You will need to then get the strlen of the name and subtract that with the number you will be constraining the wordwrap to.

Consider the following code: *Each time the `wordwrap()` function wraps the newline, it will subtract the length of the name in characters and the parenthesis and space in the span tag to ensure there is never more than 40 characters on the new line within the second span tag. Basically this creates the illusion of a perfect indention which is the width of the name passed into the function.*

CSS:

```css
.flexbox {
    display:flex;
}
```

PHP:

```php
function wrapText($name, $str, $limit){    
    //--> get the string length of the name, 
    //--> the + 2 below is for the parenthesis and $nbsp; (space)
    $nameLen = strlen($name) + 2;
    //--> return the wordwrap function with your variables embedded into the function
    //--> subtract the name length from the constraint     
    return "<div class='flexbox'><span>$name:&nbsp;</span><span>".wordwrap($str, $limit - $nameLen, "<br />\n")."</span></div>";    
}
```

Call the function within the HTML on a php page:

```php
<div>
  <?=wrapText($name,$str, 40)?>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

With another name much longer:

[image]

HTML structure will look like the following:

[image]

Comment: I hape updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: @vrec I have updated my answer with what I think is a better solution for your use case.

Comment: what if I need to output it to raw print (thermal printer), there is an alternative way to to the indention instead of using the css part?

Comment: You can use the word wrap function and set up a for loop to create en-spaces or some other HTML entity that is as long as the persons name, however again this will differ slightly as a html entity space will vary slightly in width from the space of other characters in the font. Not all characters are the same width and take up less or more space depending on the characters in the persons name.

Answer (score 1):

you can use chunk_split in this way:

```
    $a = "This variable contains a very long string with no purpose and really no sense just for use as example";
echo chunk_split($a, 40) ."\n";
```

And with this, you will get lines of 40 characters as example. Something like this:

```
This variable contains a very long strin
g with no purpose and really no sense ju
st for use as example
```

---

**Now, responding to your improved question, I have to say:**

According to the 
, seems like you want to output a PHP result in a advanced or mordern look&feel in HTML format.
You have to understand that's not the PHP job. That's what CSS is made for. In fact, the MVC (Model View Controller) gives you a robust way to separate the logic from the appearance because you can't manage the monitor's width of final user in realtime when the window is resized.

Said that, you can manage that with CSS using some property like "word-wrap", "overflow-wrap", and justifying the text. Seriously, is not recommended merge both concepts.

Despite that, as toy, your question...

Looks like you want to add a separation so big as the $name length, so you can do this:

```
echo chunk_split($line1, 40, "<br>". str_repeat("&nbsp;", strlen($name1)));
```

Based on my original example, this is an adapted example since it's done in text mode, you have to use the equivalent charaacter in html:
[image]

Comment: I hape updated my question, please take a look.